# RoVideoScreen not loading video

Tags: roku, brightscript

I have a Roku application that is given links to a video through the launch command.  This video is then displayed in a `roVideoScreen` object.  However, the video just doesn't load.  Assuming all the links work can anyone see what is going wrong.  Any help is appreciated.

```
count = CreateObject("roInt")
count = info.Lookup("amount").ToInt()

bitrates = CreateObject("roArray", count, false)
qualities = CreateObject("roArray", count, false)
url = CreateObject("roArray", count, false)
StreamFormat = "mp4"
title = info.Lookup("title")

index = 0

if info.DoesExist("720") = true

    url = info.Lookup("720")
    bitrates.Push(2500)
    qualities.Push("HD")
    index = index + 1
end if

if info.DoesExist("480") = true

    url = info.Lookup("480")
    bitrates.Push(1200)
    qualities.Push("SD")
    index = index + 1
end if

if info.DoesExist("360") = true

    url = info.Lookup("360")
    bitrates.Push(700)
    qualities.Push("SD")
    index = index + 1
end if

if info.DoesExist("240") = true

    url = info.Lookup("240")
    bitrates.Push(380)
    qualities.Push("SD")
    index = index + 1
end if

videoclip = CreateObject("roAssociativeArray")
videoclip.StreamBitrates = bitrates
videoclip.StreamQualities = qualities
videoclip.StreamUrls = url
videoclip.StreamFormat = StreamFormat
videoclip.Title = title

video = CreateObject("roVideoScreen")
port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
video.SetMessagePort(port)

video.SetContent(videoclip)

video.Show()
while true

end while
```

Comment: (1) don't do `info.Lookup("amount")` and `info.Lookup("360")` - do `info.amount` and `info["360"]`. (2) don't do `bitrates = CreateObject("roArray", count, false)` - instead just `bitrates = [ ]`. (3) `count = CreateObject("roInt")` is entirely unnecessary

Comment: It is unnecessary however, it makes the code more explicit and clear.

Comment: Assigning `roInt` to `count` makes no sense because a) BrightScript is a dynamic-typed language and b) type gets overridden the very next line with `Integer` primitive type which is different from the boxed `roInt`. You can take my advice or leave it - like they say "You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was declaring `url` as a array however, over righting it as a String so i needed to change the lines where I add to `url` to

```
url.SetEntry(index,info.Lookup("480"))
```